# Create shortcodes in ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, youtube, shortcode

I'm working on a website where there will be embedded a lot of YouTube videos. I want to make it a little easier to embed them into the articles of the page.

When writing this:

```
 [youtube]SOMETHING[/youtube]
```

the page should automatically create this:

```
  <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SOMETHING" 
         frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So - how do I do that? I've been searching around but haven't been able to find a right solution. Please throw your examples in ASP.NET / C#.

Comment: ASP.Net as in WebForms, ASP.Net MVC, custom framework? ASPX or Razor (CSHTML/VBHTML)? Where do you want "When writing this" - expanded while you editing in VS or some processed area on page or some data from external source like DB? Is it somehow related to Wordpress (based on tag)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591608/using-wordpress-style-short-codes-in-asp-net

Comment: [There is a work I did on the link. You can examine it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591608/using-wordpress-style-short-codes-in-asp-net) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591608/using-wordpress-style-short-codes-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Creating shortcodes in ASP.NET is easy as a custom solution. Before you output your article do

```
String html = "[YOUTUBE]Something[\\YOUTUBE]";

String replacementHtml = "<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

Regex shortcodeRegex = new Regex(@"\[YOUTUBE\]([^\[\\]+)\[\\YOUTUBE\]");

String result = shortcodeRegex.Replace(html, replacementHtml);
```

Take note of the `$1` in the replacementHtml. This is what is replaced by what is internal to the match.

Then output the result to the page.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me, how I can use it globally? If I want to use the same code on multiple pages, I don't want to have the same code on all of them.

Comment: When you get html from your database or file, it would most likely all come from the same code in a class library. Just put the editing on that before it is passed back to the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress style short code application. It replaces the value [short code /] in the content coming from the database or in the variable in the variable with the user control content.

App_Code--> modul_islemler.cs

```
public class modul_islemler 
{
 public static  string modul_olustur(string data){
    string aranan = @"\[(.*?)\/\]";
    Regex objRegex = new Regex(aranan);
    MatchCollection objCol = objRegex.Matches(data); 
    foreach (Match item in objCol)
    {data = data.Replace(item.Groups[0].Value, modul_yaz(item.Groups[1].Value.ToString()));
    }
    return data;
}
public static  string modul_yaz(string sayfa)
{       
    string[] ayir = sayfa.Split(' ');
    ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
    foreach (string a in ayir)
    {
        myAL.Add(a);
    }
    if (myAL.Count < 2) myAL.Add("");
    return LoadControl("~/plugins/" + myAL[0] + "/" + myAL[0] + ".ascx");
 }
 public static string LoadControl(string UserControlPath)
 {
   FormlessPage page = new FormlessPage();
    page.EnableViewState = false;
    // Create instance of the user control
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(UserControlPath);
    page.Controls.Add(userControl);
    //Write the control Html to text writer
    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

    //execute page on server
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, false);

    // Clean up code and return html
    return textWriter.ToString();
   }
   public class FormlessPage : Page
{
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
}
```

page.aspx

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <div class="detail">
 <div class="container">
  <asp:Literal ID="icerikLtrl" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  </div>
  </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

page.aspx.cs --> [slide_plugins /] shortcodes

```
public partial class page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  string txt="<div>blala [slide_plugins /] blabla</div>";
  icerikLtrl.Text = modul_islemler.modul_olustur(txt);
 }
```

plugins/slide_plugins/slide_plugins.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Txt1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
```

plugins/slide_plugins/slide_plugins.ascx.cs

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    //kontrol yüklendiğinde çalışacak kodlar       
    base.OnLoad(e);       
}
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{               
    base.OnInit(e);
    InitializeComponent();        
}
  private void InitializeComponent()
{
   btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);      

}
 protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// not working....
{
    Txt1.Text = "Example";   // not working....    

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer code only answer's doesn't tend to help much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use to handle youtube shortcodes

```
<Extension> Public Function ConvertYouTubeShortCode(text As String) As String
    Dim regex__1 As String = "\[youtube:.*?\]"
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, regex__1)
    If matches.Count = 0 Then
        Return text
    End If
    Dim width As Int32 = 620
    Dim height As Int32 = 349
    Dim BaseURL As String = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
    For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        Dim length As Int32 = "[youtube:".Length
        Dim mediaFile As String = matches(i).Value.Substring(length, matches(i).Value.Length - length - 1)
        Dim player As String = "<div class=""video-container""><iframe width=""{2}"" height=""{3}"" src=""{4}{1}"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>"
        Return text.Replace(matches(i).Value, [String].Format(player, i, mediaFile, width, height, BaseURL))
    Next
End Function
```