# C# Replace Shortcode with PartialView in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have defined few shortCode in Database. When i am displaying in view, ShortCode not replacing with the PartalView defined in the Dictionary.

Here is my code:

@{

```
        var input = "<div>Hello This is Same</div><div>{partv _AllPages}</div><div>Some Content</div><div>{partv _AllPost}</div>";
        var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
        { 
            { "{partv _AllPages}", Html.Partial("_AllPages").ToString()},
            { "{partv _AllPost}", Html.Partial("_AllPost").ToString()}
        };
        var output = replacements.Aggregate(input, (current, replacement) => current.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value));
    }
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(output))
```

Comment: Could you pls describe your issue clearly ? And we need to know the normal phenomen, I also found [a good sample about shortcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215865/7687666).

Comment: in DataBase i am creating a field Description. There i am storing HTML text along with Few Short code. When i display Description in view. I want the short Code to replace with Partial view. Like we do in WordPress/Joomla. In DataBase i define ShortCode. I want that sortCode replaced with PartialView

Comment: This is the message i am getting on the screen microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.ViewBuffer